# Issue with ASIO io_service to run multiple time

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-thread, asyncsocket

In my question. I am a client and my purpose is only to write at server whenever required not everytime.

I have one singleton class(Caller class) in which I call my client program(Client) to write any message on server and 
then calling boost::asio::io_service::run through one thread .
My client program(Client) is also singleton class.

My program works fine if server is already running. Because client will connect to server in first instance. But if server restarts or not running then fist I have to check whenever server is running or not before writing the message.

To check each time whether server is available or not I have to call  Caller::run() and running io_service.

Without running io_service I can't check whether server is running or not as I am using all sync in my program.
Everything is in async (asycn connect, sync write)

My problem is that sometime my program goes to in +D1 state(Uninterruptible sleep) and then I am not able to close my program.
Is this due to io_service() ?

How can I check whether server is on or not without running io_service?

```
 class Caller
 {
  public:

  static Caller* getInstance()
  {
   static Caller Caller;
   return &Caller;
  }

  void run() 
  {
    pWork.reset( new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service) );

    ////////////calling client program//////////////// 
    Client::getInstance(io_service)->start();

    thread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
  }     

  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> pWork;

  boost::thread thread;

 private:
  Caller()
  {
  }
  ~Caller()
  {
    pWork.reset();
    thread.join();
  }
}; 


///////////my client program (Singleton Class)//////////////////
//////message write function///////////

void Client::sendResponse(std::string& messag)                      
{                                                                              
  boost::system::error_code error;                                           
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = socket().remote_endpoint(error);    

  if ( error ) 
  {                                                               
    DEBUG_2("could not write: ",boost::system::system_error(error).what());    
    this->stop(); /////this will close the socket////
    Caller::getInstance()->run();   
    //////it will call the caller program to call the  connect function of client program /////
  }                                                                           
  else
    boost::asio::async_write(                                                         
      _socket,                                                                      
      boost::asio::buffer( message.c_str(), message.size()),
      _strand.wrap(                                                                 
        boost::bind(                                                                
          &Client::writeHandler,                                             
          this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,                                         
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred  
}                                                                              


 Client *Client::getInstance(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
  {
    if (!Client)
    {
      Client = new Client(io_service);
    }
    return Client;
  }
```

Can I design in this way that I just write to the server and no need to run io_service again and again.
or do I need to call io_service::reset()
Am I using work in correct way ?

How can I stop or abort this gracefully ?
by calling io_servie::stop or joining this thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical methodology to detect connection validity is to perform an `async_read()` after connecting successfully. When `async_read()` callback indicates the `boost::asio::error::eof` error, your application should react appropriately:

1. reconnect, perhaps with a timeout delay
2. terminate gracefully
3. abort

It sounds like you need option #1. When written correctly, your application should only need to invoke `io_service::run()` once, the event loop will constantly have work to do.

---

If you don't want to read from the socket to detect closure, instantiate a [`work`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) object and keep it in scope for the duration of your program. This will ensure the `io_service` always has work to do. When your `async_write` completion handler is invoked with an error, react as necessary for your application as suggested previously.

Comment: 1. I can't use async_read as I don't need to read from server.
2. If server is not on then client will try to connect to server whenever client needs to write any message on server, So timeout delay is not possible.
3. Please let me know how can I terminate gracefully ?
by calling io_service::stop or join this thread ?
4. How can I abort ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.
It means I just need keep io_service in scope and whenever I need to reconnect I just need to call start function to connect to server from function Client::sendResponse(std::string& message). No need to run io_service again.
and It is working fine. 
Thanks